# How to move file between azure blob containers using java?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-java-sdk

How i can move file from one blob container to another using java api.

i am using below SKD from microsoft.

```
Gradle dependency: compile group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-storage-blob', version: '12.8.0'
```

how i can move a file between blob storage using java api.

Answer (score 2):

[BlobClientBase.beginCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.specialized.blobclientbase.begincopy?view=azure-java-stable) Method is used to copy the data at the source URL to a blob.

Code sample:

If the containers are in the different storage accounts:

```
String connectStr = "source storage account connection string";
String destconnectStr="destination storage account connection string";

// Create a BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connectStr).buildClient();

BlobServiceClient destblobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(destconnectStr).buildClient();

BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("test");

BlobContainerClient destcontainer=destblobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("destcontainer");

PagedIterable<BlobItem> blobs= containerClient.listBlobs();
for (BlobItem blobItem : blobs) {

    System.out.println("This is the blob name: " + blobItem.getName());
    BlobClient blobClient=containerClient.getBlobClient(blobItem.getName());
    BlobClient destblobclient=destcontainer.getBlobClient(blobItem.getName());
    destblobclient.beginCopy(blobClient.getBlobUrl(),null);

}
```

If the containers are in the same storage account:

```
String connectStr = "storage account connection string";

// Create a BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connectStr).buildClient();

BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("test");

BlobContainerClient destcontainer=blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("testcontainer");

PagedIterable<BlobItem> blobs= containerClient.listBlobs();
for (BlobItem blobItem : blobs) {

    System.out.println("This is the blob name: " + blobItem.getName());
    BlobClient blobClient=containerClient.getBlobClient(blobItem.getName());
    BlobServiceSasSignatureValues sas = new BlobServiceSasSignatureValues(OffsetDateTime.now().plusHours(1),
    BlobContainerSasPermission.parse("r"));
    String sasToken = blobClient.generateSas(sas);

    BlobClient destblobclient=destcontainer.getBlobClient(blobItem.getName());
    destblobclient.beginCopy(blobClient.getBlobUrl()+ "?" + sasToken,null);

}
```

[BlobClientBase.copyFromUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.specialized.blobclientbase.copyfromurl?view=azure-java-stable) Method can also be used for this, but it will wait for the copy to complete before returning a response. You could choose what you need.

Comment: how i can move file from specific path for example /test/test.zip from container A to container B..

looks like beginCopy will copy the file it won't perform move operation right?

Comment: and container are in same storage account

Comment: You need to copy to container B then delete the blob in container A. There is no direct method. There is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/copy-blobs-from-command-line-and-code/7-move-blobs-using-net-storage-client) with .Net, you could refer to the steps of moving files.